# What restrictions has cursor in GraphQL Connections for Relay?

Tags: connection, graphql, relay

I almost finished package for NodeJS https://github.com/nodkz/graphql-compose-connection which allows to construct connection types for graphql types builded with graphql-compose.

This package completly follows to Relay Cursor Connections Specification (https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm) with great additions: `filter` arg (for filtering records) and `sort` arg (for sorting records by unique indexes).

So I have following questions about cursor uniqueness:

**1) Should cursor be unique among different types?**

**2) Should cursor be unique among one connection with different args?**

Eg. in UserConnection I have filter arg. And I want display all users in first list and online users in the second (2 lists simultaneously on the page). One user with same cursor may be exists in both list.

**3) If Relay gets similar cursors in one connection, will it throw error?**

**4) Should be cursor base64 encoded, or it may contains stringified json object?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Should cursor be unique among different types?**

If your question here is "should cursors be globally unique", the answer is no. They are not like IDs, which must be globally unique in Relay in order to facilitate refetching (for diffing). A cursor could be as simple as something like "100" or "101", although in practice often contain something more descriptive and/or structured than that.

**2) Should cursor be unique among one connection with different args?**

> Eg. in UserConnection I have filter arg. And I want display all users
>   in first list and online users in the second (2 lists simultaneously
>   on the page). One user with same cursor may be exists in both list.

This is an implementation-specific thing. The point of the cursor is to enable pagination, and its contents are arbitrary. Simply, it should contain enough information, in conjunction with the other arguments on the connections, to enable your GraphQL schema on the server to be able to determine what it should return for the next (`after`) or previous (`before`) page.

**3) If Relay gets similar cursors in one connection, will it throw error?**

I am not sure if it will, but you could try it and find out. Even if it doesn't throw an error, it probably wouldn't make sense. The purpose of a cursor is to allow you to specify a relative starting point for a pagination, so if the cursor "x" appears at two different places in a connection, what does "first 10 after x" mean?

**4) Should be cursor base64 encoded, or it may contains stringified json object?**

The Base64 is something we do by convention, not because it is mandated, in order to make it clearer that cursors should be considered opaque tokens whose internal structure should not be relied upon. They're implementation-specific. So, I believe you could use a JSON string if you wanted, but there is some benefit to Base64 encoding it.

Comment: Disclaimer: I work on Relay, not GraphQL, but I've answered these to the best of my understanding.

Comment: thanks a lot. Your disclaimer, was my requirement ;) I needed an answer from Relay team, that you do not have specific manipulations with `cursors` in Relay. So https://github.com/nodkz/graphql-compose-connection are ready for production.

Comment: Hi @wincent, when you say the cursor should be something simple like 100, or 101; how would that be generated. What I am wondering is, if, for example, your BE speaks to a database, (let's say MySQL for argument's sake) then how would a cursor like 100 or 101 translate to a position in the DB (the only way I can see this being possible is by using an ID field?)